# Can/How does one make Zend's default (or any other autoloader on the stack) ignore a class?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have written a custom autoloader and put it on top of the stack. I have a number of classes that I want to be removed/not shown to the rest of the stack, how can I do this? Currently my loader traps for the class name but does nothing, eg...

```
function MyAutoLoader($class) {
  if (substr($class, 0, 3) == 'My_') {
    // i dont want any other loaders to even know this class exists
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the namespace was registered. By unregistering the namespace I took care of the problem.